# What is the best translation for "livestreaming"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin, new-latin, modern-life

I am looking for a brief and accurate expression to say "livestreaming" in Latin. Classical or New Latin style, or coined word are all okay. Are there any options?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps "transmissio directa"
"Imagine vivida"

Comment: Could you provide some context for your suggestions? What do they mean and why do you feel they're good options?

Comment: I just translated from my language. "Transmissão ao vivo" "ao vivo"

Comment: Neither of your suggestions actually translates either of those directly. Why is "imagine vivida" in the ablative? Presumably it's an instrumental, but this should be explained in your answer.

Comment: Why not?
Livestream in my language is a "transmission in real time" there's nothing to do with a stream or river. I said I translated from my language, not from English. If you want something that makes sense in English, just wait for an English native. Neo-latin is really hard to translate.

Comment: Neo-Latin is hard to translate when you use machine translation without understanding what you're doing, sure.

Comment: Leave me alone, man!

Comment: I have to second Cairnarvon on this. Can you please add more context to your answer in the answer itself? The comments are meant for clarification, but anything showing your reasoning and process is helpful. One line suggestions are liable to be converted to comments instead.